# Way to Encrypt(Password protect) .xls file which is already created

Tags: java, excel, encryption, apache-poi

I have successfully Encrypted an existing Excel file (.xlsx format) but i have no idea how to Encryt Excel file of .xls format , so far i have zipped and then encrypted the .xls but i want the Excel file(.xls) to be encrypted.

i have used POI for these operations.

```
if(!CSVToEXCEL.pw.equals("NA")){

                if(CSVToEXCEL.oformat.equals("xlsx")){
                    POIFSFileSystem fs = new POIFSFileSystem();
                    EncryptionInfo info = new EncryptionInfo(fs, EncryptionMode.agile);

                    Encryptor enc = info.getEncryptor();
                    enc.confirmPassword(CSVToEXCEL.pw);

                    OPCPackage opc = OPCPackage.open(new File(CSVToEXCEL.opath), PackageAccess.READ_WRITE);
                    OutputStream os = enc.getDataStream(fs);
                    opc.save(os);
                    opc.close();

                    FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(CSVToEXCEL.opath);
                    fs.writeFilesystem(fos);
                    System.out.println("File created..."+CSVToEXCEL.opath);
                    fos.close();    
            }
                else {
                    // if file is of '.xls' format
                    System.out.println("xls cannot be Encrypted...");
                    ZipAndProtectReport zipAndProtectReport = new ZipAndProtectReport();
                    String xlsoutputzip = zipAndProtectReport.ZipAndProtectMethod(CSVToEXCEL.opath,CSVToEXCEL.pw);
                    System.out.println("Zip Created..... path: "+xlsoutputzip);             
                    }
            }

        else 
            System.out.println("File Created....."+CSVToEXCEL.opath);
    }
```

CSVToEXCEL is class name , CSVToEXCEL.opath is the output path location, CSVToEXCEL.pw is password ZipAndProtectReport is another class for zipping and then password protecting.

i want to know how can i make .xls to be password protected without zipping it.

Comment: Did you [try reading the Apache POI documentation on password protection and encryption](https://poi.apache.org/encryption.html)? If not, what happens when you do?

Comment: yeah i had already read it , not working. till now what i have discovered is that only some EasyXLS api could do this.

Answer (score 1):

Try this link http://www.quicklyjava.com/create-password-protected-excel-using-apache-poi/.

Since you already are using POI, it would be easier to use this.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can create a xlsx file,and put the xls file's data into xlsx file,and encryt xlsx file?